# wx.ListCtrl not displaying strings added by SetStringItem

Tags: python, wxpython

Any help is appreciated this has been driving me insane

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1)

        # dp = DownloadPanel(self)
        # dl = dp.download_list
        dl = wx.ListCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        dl.InsertColumn(0, "File")
        dl.InsertColumn(1, "Progress")
        dl.InsertColumn(2, "State")
        dl.SetStringItem(0, 0, "FILE")
        dl.SetStringItem(0, 1, "PERCENT")
        dl.SetStringItem(0, 2, "STATE")
        dl.SetStringItem(1, 0, "FILE")
        dl.SetStringItem(1, 1, "PERCENT")
        dl.SetStringItem(1, 2, "STATE")
        dl.SetStringItem(2, 0, "FILE")
        dl.SetStringItem(2, 1, "PERCENT")
        dl.SetStringItem(2, 2, "STATE")
        dl.SetStringItem(3, 0, "FILE")
        dl.SetStringItem(3, 1, "PERCENT")
        dl.SetStringItem(3, 2, "STATE")

        self.Refresh()
        dl.Refresh()
        self.Update()
        dl.Update()
        self.Layout()
        dl.Layout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = wx.App(False)
    f = Frame()
    f.Show()
    a.MainLoop()
```

Ok when I run this the items aren't display, what am I doing wrong? I'm adding the items. Ahhhh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `InsertStringItem` to start a new row:

```
import wx
import sys

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, size=(380, 230))

        dl = wx.ListCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        dl.InsertColumn(0, 'File')
        dl.InsertColumn(1, 'Progress')
        dl.InsertColumn(2, 'State')

        for row in range(3):
            labels = [l+str(row) for l in "FILE PERCENT STATE".split()]
            # sys.maxint inserts at the end of the list
            index = dl.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, labels[0])
            dl.SetStringItem(index, 1, labels[1])
            dl.SetStringItem(index, 2, labels[2])

        self.Show(True)

app = wx.App()
Frame(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

yields

[image]

I learned this by comparing your code with the sample found [here](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/advanced/). The examples [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/ListControls) may also help you.

Comment: I changed my answer to show how to do this with SetStringItem.

Comment: ok thanks I think I get how the list ctrl items structure works now thanks